# c++ pointer to class member

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am learning doubly linked list in C++. There is one line on the book that I don't understand, anyone can help with it? Many thanks. Especially I don't understand the 2nd and 3rd lines.

```
void insert(const E& it) {
  curr->next = curr->next->prev =
  new Link<E>(it, curr, curr->next);
  cnt++; 
}
```

The Link class is claimed as:
    public:
      E element;
      Link* next;
      Link* prev;

Comment: Which bit don't you understand

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a new version of your insert method rewritten for clarity:

```
void insert(const E& it) {
    Link<E>* after = curr->next;
    Link<E>* newLink = new Link<E>(it, curr, after);
    curr->next = after;
    after->prev = after;

    cnt++;
}
```

The version that confused you had combined too many steps into one statement.

When I was learning linked lists, I found it really helpful to draw diagrams where each node was a box that had lines leading out of it that pointed to previous and next.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the second line you have an `=`, so the second and third line are one statement.

It has to be red from right to left:  First you create a `Link<E>` which seems to be the constructor (of a template class Link, using type E), then you put the value in `curr->next->prev,`  and then you put the same value in `curr->next`.

If you read the statement in english, it means *"create a new element, and make it the previous element of the next element, as well as the next element of the current element"*.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand a little. May need more practice. One more question, how comes if there is no new Link created. This line ends before the third "="? I think this is the main reason I get confused.

Comment: Excellent question !  Indeed, this code doesn't work if theere is no item in the list (i.e. curr==nullptr), unless your autor has managed to ensure that there is always at least a dummy element in he list.  You are correct, proper style and indentation is important because it can confuse people, even if correct for the compiler that knows the statemen doesn't end with a newline but with a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, a `Link` contains a `Link* next` pointing to the next node, a `Link* prev` pointing to the previous node, and presumably an `E value` type that contains the actual data for the node.

Given a `curr` node, which is probably a global variable pointing to the "current" node, `insert` creates a new `Link` with the value `it` and inserts it between `curr` and `curr->next`.

For example, given a link set `A -> B -> C`, with `B` as the `curr` node, it creates a new `Link` (call it `X`) with `B` as the previous node, and `C` as the next node.  Then it assigns that new node to `B->next` and `C->prev`, resulting in `A -> B -> X -> C`.  Finally, it increments the `cnt` value (also probably a global), which presumably keeps a tally of the total number of `Link`s in the container.